# preg_match list of urls without spaces

Tags: php, regex

I have this list of urls:

```
http://test1.google.com/test1/12345http://test2.google.com/test2/12345http://test3.google.com/test4/12345http://test1.google.com/test1/12345http://test1.google.com/test1/12345http://test1.google.com/test1/12345http://test1.google.com/test1/12345http://test1.google.com/test1/12345
```

It's just an example, I want to preg_match_all a list of valid urls that doesn't have space to seperate between them, so, I will get it in an array and each cell is different url.

Comment: And how is your script supposed to know where one URL ends and another begins? Can you _guarantee_ that `http://` will never be found inside a URL?

Comment: Also could you please consider putting the effort in to write full sentences, capital letters and punctuation. Thanks.

Comment: yes its only in a beginning of new url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for preg_match IMHO:

```
<?php
$links = 'http://test1.google.com/test1/12345http://test2.google.com/test2/12345http://test3.google.com/test4/12345http://test1.google.com/test1/12345http://test1.google.com/test1/12345http://test1.google.com/test1/12345http://test1.google.com/test1/12345http://test1.google.com/test1/12345';

$links = array_map(function($chunk){return 'http://'.$chunk;}, explode('http://', $links));
array_shift($links);
print_r($links);
```

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/908w8Z), Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => http://test1.google.com/test1/12345
    [1] => http://test2.google.com/test2/12345
    [2] => http://test3.google.com/test4/12345
    [3] => http://test1.google.com/test1/12345
    [4] => http://test1.google.com/test1/12345
    [5] => http://test1.google.com/test1/12345
    [6] => http://test1.google.com/test1/12345
    [7] => http://test1.google.com/test1/12345
)
```

Comment: thanks u it solved it, but i wonder if there is a solution for 10GB text file, because when i split the file because of it's size, it cut some urls so i lose them.

Comment: @Ben: You need to parse it more manually then. With a buffer and you must define the maximum length of an URL then.